# Azure Database Unexpected server CPU Load

Tags: database, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

Has problem with azure database ( **Business** )
Prerequisites:

1. Database Take less then **1 Gb** ( *near 400 mb* )from **10 GB** available.
2. Remove rows and clear 200 MB of space. ( F*ROM unused table for dev. purpose not involved in working process* )
3. Make changes with stored procedures.

Result:

- CPU on SQL server increased to 70+% ( after 1 hour )
- application which use current database start work very slow
- Query Performance show a lot of CPU for simple procedures

My Expectations:

- Everything continue work without any CPU issue and timeout problem.

Was reproduced on test environment after restore database from backup and go over steps.

**Need help!!! ?Why this was happen, and how to prevent issues like this and which issues can be in such case?**

Problem was resolved when change server type from Business to Basic and then from Basic to Business.

Comment: Recommend you use the 'show execution plan' option on the SQL you're running.  Perhaps it is causing the rebuild of an index or a large number of transaction log writes (or a similar non-functional activity which is causing the load you are seeing).  If you don't care about the data you are deleting look at using TRUNCATE instead of a DELETE.

Comment: I need to remove just some row, not all table ( when using truncate )